# How I can use the Graph API to read folders besides Inbox? The messages REST point is only for Inbox

Tags: office365api

How do I use the Graph API to read messages from folders besides the Inbox folder.  I have used the `/me/mailFolders/` and `/me/mailFolders/$id/childfolders/` to get all the folders and subfolders for an O365 account.  Now that I have all the folder ids, I want to read the messages for those folder ids.  Can I specify the folder ids to the `/me/message` URL?

Answer (score 1):

To read a specific folder, you would do a `GET` on `/me/mailFolders/$id/messages`.